# discord bot doesn't answer the key word

Tags: python, bots, discord

I wrote the code on pycharm to create a discord bot.

Some of the code works but some does not.

This is my code:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()  

@client.event  
async def on_ready():  
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')  

@client.event
async def on_message(message): 
    id = client.get_guild(676561378265399296)
    print(f"{message.channel}: {message.author}: {message.author.name}: {message.content}")
    if message.content_find("!Hello"):
        await message.channel_send("hi ")
```

And then this is the error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\no0x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)`enter code here`
  File "C:/Users/no0x/AppData/Local/Programs/bot/bot.py", line 18, in on_message
    if message.content_find("!Hello"):
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'content_find'
```

Comment: actually when i write !hello bot don't answer but bot operate the(on_ready)and the first part of (on_massage)

Comment: the error is pretty clear, Message has no content_find action according to error
maybe make sure the message is a Message with type()

Comment: `discord.Message` doesn't have a `content_find` attribute regardless, it has a `content` attribute, which is just a string. This code should read `message.content.startswith("!Hello")` or `"!Hello" in message.content` depending on if the message has to *start* with the check or *contain* the check.

Answer (score 0):

The [Message](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#message-object) object doesn't have a `content_find`-attribute. Although it has a `content`-attribute, declared as a string, which can use the [find()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_find.htm)-method.

What you probably meant to do was `if (message.content.find("!Hello") >= 0):`, which checks if the message content contains the string `!Hello`. If you want to check if the message starts with `!Hello`, alter the comparator to `==`; alternatively you can use [startswith()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_startswith.htm).